# What should the path be in the @AtmosphereHandlerService

Tags: atmosphere

I am trying to run the chat example for atmosphere (running in glassfish). So here is my service:-

```
@AtmosphereHandlerService(
   path = "/chat",
   interceptors = {
       AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.class,
       BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor.class
   }
)
public class Chat extends OnMessage<String>
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Chat.class);

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void onMessage(AtmosphereResponse response, String message) throws IOException {
        response.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.readValue(message, ChatMessage.class)));
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
      "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.atmosphere.samples.chat.angular</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*/chat</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I deploy so that the context root is /atmospheretest/chat

and I get the following log output:-

```
[#|2013-11-05T16:28:21.597+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|
16:28:21.590 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:21.599+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:21.598 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.a.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$BytecodeBasedAnnotationProcessor being used
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:21.681+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:21.681 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.a.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Found Annotation in org.atmosphere.samples.chat.angular.Chat being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:21.685+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:21.685 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.a.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Found Annotation in org.atmosphere.samples.chat.Chat being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:21.865+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:21.865 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] DEBUG o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Scanning all classes on the classpath
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.761+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.761 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] WARN  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere's Service annotation not supported. Please add https://github.com/rmuller/infomas-asl as dependency or your own AnnotationProcessor to support @Service
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.801+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.800 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] WARN  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\Sun\AppServer21\lib\Does not exist\lib\dbstate.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:143) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.ZipFileIterator.<init>(ZipFileIterator.java:63) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.ClassFileIterator.next(ClassFileIterator.java:117) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.AnnotationDetector.detect(AnnotationDetector.java:367) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.AnnotationDetector.detect(AnnotationDetector.java:255) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$BytecodeBasedAnnotationProcessor.scanAll(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:369) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.scanAll(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:197) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoConfigureService(AtmosphereFramework.java:2235) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:674) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:582) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:88) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:77) [atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0-beta1.jar:2.1.0-beta1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:848) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:382) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106) [appserv-rt.jar:9.1]
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.812+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.812 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Auto detecting atmosphere handlers /WEB-INF/classes/
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.834+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.834 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.839+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.839 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.863+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.863 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] DEBUG o.a.c.GlassFishv2CometSupport - Created CometContext for atmosphere context: /atmospheretest/atmosphere
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.863+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.863 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.864+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.864 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.DefaultHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.867+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.867 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.867+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.867 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.868+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.868 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.868+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.868 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.871+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.871 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.871+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.871 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.871+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.871 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.878+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.878 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] WARN  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - No BroadcasterCache configured. Broadcasted message between client reconnection will be LOST. It is recommended to configure the org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.878+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.878 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using Broadcaster: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.879+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.878 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.879+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.879 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Shared ExecutorService supported: true
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.928+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.928 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Messaging Thread Pool Size: 2147483647
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.928+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.928 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.928+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.928 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.928+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.928 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.928+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.928 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - HttpSession supported: false
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.928+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.928 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.929+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.929 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishv2CometSupport running under container: Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.952+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.952 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere Framework 2.1.0-beta1 started.
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.952+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.952 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - 

    For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
    http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.958+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;|16:28:24.958 [httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1] ERROR o.a.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - No AtmosphereHandler found. Make sure you define it inside WEB-INF/atmosphere.xml or annotate using @___Service
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:24.959+1100|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-1;_RequestID=efa39eb6-d078-4b50-b0f7-5a06b5e23f56;|StandardWrapperValve[AtmosphereServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet AtmosphereServlet threw exception
org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler found. Make sure you define it inside WEB-INF/atmosphere.xml or annotate using @___Service
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:188)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:165)
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishv2CometSupport.service(GlassFishv2CometSupport.java:119)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1725)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:198)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:184)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:872)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
|#]

[#|2013-11-05T16:28:25.391+1100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=45;_ThreadName=Thread-9904;|16:28:25.390 [Thread-9904] INFO  o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.0.7
|#]
```

What am I doing wrong? Specifically, what should the path be for the service? I have tried both /chat and /atmospheretest/chat.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that file, which seems to break the annotation processor

```
C:\dev\Sun\AppServer21\lib\Does not exist\lib\dbstate.jar
```

Comment: The file does not exist. I think the problem was that I was targetting 1.7, which was what was causing the weird error (the file does not exists). I have fixed this now, but after that fix, I had to configure my glassfish server to use comet.